# java loop execution program stopped after certain time

Tags: java, multithreading, bash, infinite-loop, execution

```
public Test(){}


public void run() {
    System.out.println("calls");

    Map<String, Indexation> mi = new HashMap<>();
    String[] spl = compo.split("[\\s@&.?$+-:_!^{}']+");


    int ct = 0;

    try {
        System.out.println("calls Prep");
        PreparedStatement p = GetConnexion.getPST("select * from mtg where ogvideo is null and title!=? and alfa!=? and st=? order by id desc limit 1");
        PreparedStatement pu = GetConnexion.getPST("update mtg set st=? where id=?");
        p.setString(1, "");
        p.setString(2, "");
        p.setInt(3, 0);
        ResultSet r = p.executeQuery();
        while (r.next()) {

            int id = r.getInt("id");
            pu.setInt(1, 2);
            pu.setInt(2, id);
            pu.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println(id + "--------");
            String title = r.getString("title");
            String alfa = r.getString("alfa");
            String compo = title + " " + alfa;
            String url = r.getString("url");
            compo = compo.toLowerCase();
            String[] spl = compo.split("[.=#&,;x|<>!\\s\\-:_\\?\\p{P} \\t\\n\\r]+");

            System.out.println("<--->");
            for (String s : spl) {
                System.out.println("+++++++++++++");
                ct = getFrequencies(spl, s) + getOccu(url, s);
                System.out.println("----coll----");
                Indexation i = new Indexation(alfa, title, url, ct, s,
                        s + url);
                if (s.length() > 2 &&
                        !getAllStpW().contains(s) &&
                        !getDirty().contains(s)) mi.put(s, i);
            }

        }
        r.close();
        p.close();
        System.out.println("end");
    } catch (Exception f) {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The program above is Test.java which I inherited from Thread.
I wanted to execute it in loop all the time in a linux server,
this is the bash script: test.sh

```
while true 
do
java -Xms40m -Xmx712m -verbose:gc  -jar test.jar
```

done

The execution of the script is good without any exceptions but after certain time it stopped and displays the id of the table and the message ++++++++++.
I have this a problem for a long time. I'm persuaded to kill the process id of the application each time!

What I should i do?

Comment: The code is not complete, I can't see a catch block. And that `enter code here` has nothing to do here.

Comment: Might not be relevant to the problem, but are you sure you didn't mean to escape the `.` character at the beginning of your split regex?

Comment: no at all the code is fine it's executed without any warnings or any exception the exact problem is that it stopped after an arbitrary moment